# Data Analysis using Python--Reading Text File

Tags: python

I have a text file structure like:

```
X   Y   Home
X   Y   School
```

X and Y are times and the last column is a location. How can I use python to assess the X and Y element where the 3rd Column is Home?

Note: I have already opened the text file. If you feel I am asking to much, I would appreciate a link to a place that tells how to do something like this. Also, X and Y are not numbers they are strings: ex. 4:30 AM

Comment: How do you distinguish between spaces in X and Y (like "4:30 AM") and field separators?

Comment: Well, I am going to treat them like 2 columns and combine them after I read them.

Comment: It really depends on what your trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the contents of the file have been dumped to a variable, one way is to parse every line like so:

```
for line in file_content:
     columns = line.split()
     x_1 = columns[0]
     x_2 = columns[1]
     home = columns[2]
     ...
     ...
```

Basically the `split` distinguishes X, Y, Home and School and places them into a list.
So ultimately, `columns` is a list containing `[X, Y, Home]` regardless of the type of data.

Comment: So the "for line in file_content:" will loop through all the lines in file content (variable containing all of the file contents)?

Comment: Yes, exactly (assuming formatting does not cause any issues)